# Loader is stuck on Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

Basically the loader inside this page does not disappear after the page is loaded, some have fixed this by fixing console errors (I have none) other by fixing their onepage.phtml (Looks good to me) with nothing else to go off i'm hoping to find some kind of solution here.

**What the loader looks like before its fully loaded, looks normal.**
[image: What the loader looks like before]
**What the loader looks life after, now missing its data-mage-init**
[image]

**Inside app\design\frontend\pcnametag\pcnametag_canada\Magento_Checkout\templates\onepage.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            ga('send','event','Checkout','Step 1 - Checkout Method', {nonInteraction: true});
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="checkout" data-bind="scope:'checkout'" class="checkout-container">
    <div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
                 alt="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Loading...') ?>"
                 style="position: absolute;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#checkout": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        window.checkoutConfig = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() ?>;
        // Create aliases for customer.js model from customer module
        window.isCustomerLoggedIn = window.checkoutConfig.isCustomerLoggedIn;
        window.customerData = window.checkoutConfig.customerData;
    </script>
    <script>
        require([
            'mage/url',
            'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
        ], function(url, blockLoader) {
            blockLoader("<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>");
            return url.setBaseUrl('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBaseUrl() ?>');
        })
    </script>
</div>
```

**No errors in the console, everything in network tab coming back as 200**
[image]

Comment: check in error report sometimes it is not displayed on the frontend